# Why is $\prod_{k=1}^n (1-2^{-k}) \geq 1/4$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The title says it all: I have seen it claimed that  $\prod_{k=1}^n (1-2^{-k}) \geq 1/4$ for any $n \geq 1$, but I cannot prove this. I would like a proof of this fact.

Comment: Note that it's greater than $(1-1/2)(1-1/4)(1-1/8-1/16-\ldots)=1/2\cdot 3/4\cdot 3/4=9/32>1/4$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: Show that, given $a,b \in (0,1)$ the inequality $$(1-a)(1-b) \ge 1-(a+b)$$ holds. Use this to conclude $$\prod^{\infty}_{k=2} (1-2^{-k}) \ge 1-\left(\sum^{\infty}_{k=2} 2^{-k}\right)$$  $$ = 1 - 1/2 =1/2.$$

Can you take it from there. If the inequality
$$\prod^{\infty}_{k=2} (1-2^{-k}) \ge 1/2$$ holds,
then what can you say about $$\prod^{\infty}_{k=1} (1-2^{-k}) = \frac{1}{2}×\prod^{\infty}_{k=2} (1-2^{-k}).$$

Comment: Yes, thank you!